# How to inject HibernateTemplate in HibernateDaoSupport

Tags: spring, hibernate

I use spring version 5.0.1, hibernate version 5.2.12.

When I call getHibernateTemplate (), I get null

what am I doing wrong?

Dao confif:

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:hibernate.properties"})
@ComponentScan("ru.bochkarev.hmcs.dao")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
public class DaoConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("ru.bochkarev.hmcs.model");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        try {
            sessionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager(){
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate() {
        return new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory());
    }
}
```

.................................................................

Implement dao:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class DaoTest extends HibernateDaoSupport {

    public void save(TestModel testModel) {
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(testModel);
    }
}
```

When I call getHibernateTemplate (), I get null

Comment: That cannot be `null` if it would Spring would break during startup. Which means you are doing something like `new DaoTest()` in your code instead of using a Spring provided instance. Next to that the use of `HibernateTemplate` has been advised not to use since Hibernate 3.0.1 instead use the plain hibernate session factory with `getCurrentSession`.

Comment: Thank you, it works for me!, and I'm going to use getCurrentSession.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for your DAO class and let us know if it works.

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class DaoTest {

@Autowired
private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

public void save(TestModel testModel) {
    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(testModel);
}
}
```

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'daoTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'hibernateTemplate';

Comment: maybe this is not the best way, use HibernateDaoSupport ?